# How to add a new URL for an existing Website which point to different path?

Tags: iis, dns

We have an existing website say example.com.ph/abc. Now we want to create a new URL abc.example.ph which will point to example.com.ph/abc. Website user should not see any redirect, they should still see abc.example.ph as the website in browser. How can we implement this?
Can we have a CNAME created Domain Name abc.example.ph -> CNAME: example.com.ph/abc OR abc.example.ph -> CNAME: example.com.ph and then have a server level redirect to /abc

Thanks

Comment: Modify site binding(s) to accept requests on `abc.example.ph` and then set up reverse proxying. It won't be a simple DNS change.

Comment: Use your second solution. You cannot have path `/abc` in the DNS record.

Comment: You can use the ARR module in IIS to configure a reverse proxy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing